# Constructor value failed to get the value and assign to variable

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I try to implement Greedy Best First Search. 
My graph and heuristic is this:

[image]

Source: S destination: G. The proper way is: S A C E G.

The problem that I see there is that he don't take hNod from constructor, when I declared the Node it was: `Node s = new Node("S", 12);`
I printed out the hNod of nodes in my attempt to debugging but I don't get where the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
package com.gbfs.algorithm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

class Node{
    public String numeNod;
    public int hNod;
    public Node parent;
    public Edge[] adjacencies = new Edge[]{};

    public Node(String numeNod, int hNod){
            this.numeNod = numeNod;
            hNod = this.hNod;
    }

    public String toString(){
            return numeNod;
    }    
}

class Edge{
    public Node target;

    public Edge[] adjacencies = new Edge[]{};

    public Edge(Node target){
            this.target = target;
    }
}

public class GreedyBFS {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Node s = new Node("S", 12);
        Node a = new Node("A", 5);
        Node b = new Node("B", 5);
        Node c = new Node("C", 5);
        Node d = new Node("D", 2);
        Node e = new Node("E", 2);
        Node f = new Node("F", 1);
        Node h = new Node("H", 1);
        Node g = new Node("G", 0);

        s.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(b),
                new Edge(a)
        };

        b.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(d),
                new Edge(g)
        };

        d.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g),
                new Edge(h)
        };

        h.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(f)
        };

        a.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g),
                new Edge(c)
        };

        c.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(e)
        };

        e.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g)
        };

        g.adjacencies = new Edge[] {
                new Edge(b),
                new Edge(e),
                new Edge(c),
                new Edge(a)
        };

        f.adjacencies = new Edge[] {
                new Edge(h)
        };

        GreedyBFS(s, g);

        List<Node> path = printPath(g);

        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
}

    public static void GreedyBFS(final Node source, final Node goal) {

        Set<Node> explored = new HashSet<Node>();

        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(8, new Comparator<Node>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {

                if(o1.hNod <= o2.hNod) {
                    System.out.println("Primu if: o1.hnod " + o1.hNod);
                    System.out.println("Primu if: o2.hnod " + o2.hNod);
                    return 1;
                }

                else if(o1.hNod >= o2.hNod) {
                    System.out.println("2 if: o1.hnod " + o1.hNod);
                    System.out.println("2 if: o2.hnod " + o2.hNod);

                    return -1;
                }

                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });

        queue.add(source);

        boolean found = false;

        while( !queue.isEmpty() && !found ) {

            Node current = (Node) queue.poll();

            explored.add(current);

            if(current.numeNod.equals(goal.numeNod)){
                found = true;
            }

            for(Edge o : current.adjacencies) {

                Node child = o.target;
                int temp_hNod = current.hNod;
                System.out.println("temp_hnod = current.Hnod " + temp_hNod);

                if(explored.contains(child) && (temp_hNod >= child.hNod)) {
                    continue;
                }

                else if(!(queue.contains(child)) || (temp_hNod < child.hNod)) {

                    child.parent = current;
                    child.hNod = temp_hNod;

                    if( queue.contains(child) ) {
                        queue.remove(child);
                    }

                    queue.add(child);

                }
            }
        }        
    }

    public static List<Node> printPath(Node target){

        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

        for(Node node = target; node!=null; node = node.parent){
            path.add(node);
        }

        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;
    }

}
```

Comment: your `Comparator` makes no sense. The if-else if cases overlap with `=` . And also `hNod ` is always 0 for both Nodes.

Comment: It’s an aside, there are a couple of things I don’t understand in your data model. It the figure it seems that edges are bidirectional and have weights. In Java they seem to be modelled as unidirectional (some of them doubled by their opposite), and I don’t see the weights. I don’t know if it’s important.

Answer (score 0):

This assignment goes the wrong way: `hNod = this.hNod;`. Compare to the line above it. It should be `this.hNod = hNod;`.

Your IDE ought to have warned you there was something fishy here. When your program doesn’t behave as expected, you can very often learn the reason from trying to understand the warning message(s) you get.

Comment: I didn't see that, but now he take the value of parent and stays like this. 12 everywhere

Comment: It seems your for loop assigns the `hNod` of `current` to all the chidren of `current`. Couldn’t this be the reason for the 12 being distributed to all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I changed what you said, now I see where the problem is. I made bold what I think is wrong.

So greedy bfs compares the heuristic of each node and goes on the lowest one. So I take a node out of the queue, I say that he is a child and how do I know all the childs of that parent to can compare between them? This is where I fail, I know that in my updated code what is with bold I compare the exact same thing but I don't know how to write that in code....:(

Here is my code update:

```
package com.gbfs.algorithm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

class Node{
    public final String numeNod;
    public final int hNod;
    public Node parent;
    public Edge[] adjacencies = new Edge[]{};
    public int temp_hNod;

    public Node(String numeNod, int hNod){
            this.numeNod = numeNod;
            this.hNod = hNod;
    }

    public String toString(){
            return numeNod;
    }    
}

class Edge{
    public Node target;

    public Edge[] adjacencies = new Edge[]{};

    public Edge(Node target){
            this.target = target;
    }
}

public class GreedyBFS {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Node s = new Node("S", 12);
        Node a = new Node("A", 5);
        Node b = new Node("B", 5);
        Node c = new Node("C", 5);
        Node d = new Node("D", 2);
        Node e = new Node("E", 2);
        Node f = new Node("F", 1);
        Node h = new Node("H", 1);
        Node g = new Node("G", 0);

        s.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(b),
                new Edge(a)
        };

        b.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g),
                new Edge(d)
        };

        d.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g),
                new Edge(h)
        };

        h.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(f)
        };

        a.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g),
                new Edge(c)
        };

        c.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(e)
        };

        e.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(g)
        };

        GreedySearch(s, g);

        List<Node> path = printPath(g);

        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
}

    public static void GreedySearch(Node source, Node goal) {

        Set<Node> explored = new HashSet<Node>();

        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(8, new Comparator<Node>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {

                if(o1.hNod > o2.hNod) {
                    return 1;
                }

                else if(o1.hNod <o2.hNod){

                    return -1;
                }

                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });

        queue.add(source);

        boolean found = false;

        while( !queue.isEmpty() && !found ) {

            Node current = (Node) queue.poll();

            explored.add(current);

            if(current.numeNod.equals(goal.numeNod)){
                found = true;
            }

            for(Edge o : current.adjacencies) {

                **Node child = o.target;**

                if(explored.contains(child) && (**child.hNod >= child.hNod**)) {
                    continue;
                }

                else if(!(queue.contains(child)) || (**child.hNod < child.hNod**)) {

                    child.parent = current;

                    if( queue.contains(child) ) {
                        queue.remove(child);
                    }

                    queue.add(child);

                }
            }
        }        
    }

    public static List<Node> printPath(Node target){

        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

        for(Node node = target; node!=null; node = node.parent){
            path.add(node);
        }

        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;
    }

}
```